# From state and county names to fips in R

Tags: r, fips

I have the following data frame in R. I would like to get fips from this dataset. I tried to use `fips` function in `usmap` (https://rdrr.io/cran/usmap/man/fips.html). But I could not get fips from this function because I need to enclose double quote. Then, I tried to use `paste0(""", df$state, """)`, but I could not get it. Is there any efficient ways to get fips?

```
> df1
                   state           county
1             california             napa
2                florida       palm beach
3                florida          collier
4                florida            duval
```

**UPDATE**

I can get `"\"california\""` by using `dQuote`. Thanks. After the conversion of each column, I tried the followings. How do I deal with this issue?

```
> df1$state <- dQuote(df1$state, FALSE)
> df1$county <- dQuote(df1$county, FALSE)
> fips(state = df1$state, county = df1$county)
Error in fips(state = df1$state, county = df1$county) : 
  `county` parameter cannot be used with multiple states.

> fips(state = df1$state[1], county = df1$county[1])
Error in fips(state = df1$state[1], county = df1$county[1]) : 
  "napa" is not a valid county in "california".

> fips(state = "california", county = "napa")
[1] "06055"
```

Comment: Can you please check my updated solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `split` the dataset by `state` and apply the `fips`

```
library(usmap)
lapply(split(df1, df1$state), function(x)
      fips(state = x$state[1], county = x$county))
#$california
#[1] "06055"

#$florida
#[1] "12099" "12021" "12031"
```

---

Or with `Map`

```
lst1 <- split(df1$county, df1$state)
Map(fips, lst1, state = names(lst1))
#$california
#[1] "06055"

#$florida
#[1] "12099" "12021" "12031"
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(state) %>% 
    summarise(new = list(fips(state = first(state), county = county))) %>%
    unnest(c(new))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  state      new  
#  <chr>      <chr>
#1 california 06055
#2 florida    12099
#3 florida    12021
#4 florida    12031
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(state = c("california", "florida", "florida", 
"florida"), county = c("napa", "palm beach", "collier", "duval"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: these are excellent solutions! However, I was wondering how it would be possible to solve the issue and retain additional information in the original dataframe. When I do any of the above solutions, I lose the latitude and longitude columns present in my initial dataframe. Is it possible to keep them in a new data frame with the fips codes?

Comment: @rogues77 Can you post as a question with your data so that I can test it

Comment: @ akrun of course. Posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64978893/how-to-assign-fips-codes-to-county-names-without-deleting-columns