# How to assign fips codes to county names without deleting columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

As requested by @akrun in another thread, I am posting this question here:

I am working with the following function, which uses the `usmap` package to assign U.S. Fips codes to their respective county names.

```
pointsDF <- pointsDF %>% 
group_by(state) %>% 
summarise(new = list(fips(state = first(state), county = newcounty))) %>% 
unnest(c(new))
```

The code works, and generates the correct fips code for every county (in the column `new`). However, it deletes the `lon`, `lat`, and ```newcounty```` columns. I would like to retain those in the new data set.

Data:

```
structure(list(lon = c(-95.91241468, -90.11001628, -98.30641348, 
-80.72761498, -94.51613158, -72.84020128, -117.1440706, -73.75580388, 
-88.12470008, -71.13771368, -80.05989329, -77.51388018, -86.82375378, 
-84.38607738, -77.63199548, -95.54212968, -85.33957488, -83.87801457, 
-72.64179868, -81.97511268, -84.03534068, -98.78168858, -97.65324433, 
-84.03677428, -84.81141028, -95.52679358, -87.66701078, -96.68085988, 
-86.67083678, -81.71472778, -77.47731058, -86.81413678, -117.5823948, 
-86.67083678, -111.7277681, -95.91241468, -81.59481539, -86.2190337, 
-85.02740848, -81.57985388, -82.11529568, -85.89273868, -81.05309048, 
-77.53316098, -94.74441208, -82.98801649, -118.592851, -97.51100558, 
-84.38607738, -76.85905988, -81.90489968, -74.85185628, -117.1124004, 
-84.31196434, -84.11748248, -77.21248868, -83.09822261, -84.34831538, 
-81.6238549, -76.97949628, -111.861207, -78.98342408, -86.71827398, 
-83.73038838, -98.72683148, -85.72878268, -83.89537158, -80.72761498, 
-82.81890898, -83.35708863, -82.99332738, -81.34212698, -84.15386398, 
-77.04740688, -80.18337068, -111.6869527, -85.76044698, -117.2286916, 
-84.66893778, -81.49780508, -83.17031498, -83.39491168, -89.85832028, 
-96.87880838, -79.90396038, -86.84733458, -97.25843278, -94.62745888, 
-95.7084137, -77.15163978, -94.97595498, -80.73783528, -76.84003248, 
-80.01289956, -86.25701918, -83.19622628, -83.75358048, -97.81669738, 
-82.24173118, -80.30644058, -77.58802148, -82.38520128, -85.76044698, 
-77.47011638, -81.70904988, -74.07403258, -86.80064568, -96.95180708, 
-93.00057238, -83.55517508, -109.4923825, -81.88706528, -80.77149678, 
-74.85664718, -93.20214404, -80.11643208, -79.76923938, -96.66299208, 
-80.19681118, -84.22020618, -80.35445615, -81.15484918, -96.80223088, 
-121.2977325, -75.07909248, -117.1507284, -96.80223088, -80.36716888, 
-85.81529098, -80.01827198, -106.2207234, -91.27510708, -83.42425368, 
-81.09428658, -117.8799774, -86.84884753, -80.72551468, -84.74631358, 
-97.18762718, -79.91708618, -88.49645318, -86.59293068, -96.86661598, 
-84.74631358, -85.95063428, -80.73783528, -82.32843468, -111.7241887, 
-77.88371878, -87.88340242, -80.15304228, -81.71439878, -80.00335448, 
-82.75778868, -80.35445615, -81.95671428, -118.592851, -117.8863341, 
-81.50836418, -84.76603288, -122.5387456, -81.09472608, -78.04367708, 
-90.22537268, -80.77149678, -77.53316098, -76.63625638, -79.91708618, 
-86.60200858, -94.56251908, -80.18170988, -77.45833988, -76.06463468, 
-111.6642788, -95.52568968, -82.41273868, -95.54212968, -76.62899858, 
-76.77927328, -95.50077628, -79.89270532, -84.68528178, -84.07194978, 
-85.33927583, -79.23755148, -80.92027518, -87.66089848, -97.10632668, 
-96.29330138, -95.69761268, -80.35445615, -81.7984389, -97.08488068, 
-86.83865498, -88.00277688, -76.05303518, -81.39565538, -80.05717138, 
-85.30758928, -116.4147011, -74.10646418, -80.00335448, -77.58802148, 
-92.2634621, -97.25843278, -74.87685868, -80.11736129, -82.41015398, 
-82.25712458, -86.45776238, -84.76603288, -74.10646418, -117.6529603, 
-97.17599318, -88.31641548, -97.00634838, -77.12899408, -96.9502011, 
-97.10094718, -77.12899408, -96.40912418, -98.78168858, -81.52727668, 
-71.13771368, -77.60182838, -96.40912418, -111.9077717, -83.36196178, 
-95.47018508, -84.59305453, -77.09467349, -78.12399138, -81.78772738, 
-119.0045001, -84.23133418, -84.99435499, -86.2190337, -95.8568631, 
-83.71870668, -81.25855487, -75.98358308, -72.60981728, -84.34831538, 
-90.63745496, -97.13302838, -82.46562168, -96.85303498, -111.8443197, 
-78.52057208, -75.47299201, -96.69997516, -84.36059848, -81.7984389, 
-87.79977058, -90.98390558, -84.91059428, -77.30707598, -80.65916798, 
-98.43663508, -77.92518318, -77.21248868, -97.54358158, -77.53316098, 
-85.1805065, -97.28176868, -96.66299208, -117.2036577, -95.91636689, 
-77.99876788, -74.52641758, -85.000631, -86.84313888, -77.04740688, 
-98.64786628, -77.85974643, -82.30620698, -118.1860474, -90.48957961, 
-83.83471158, -97.59042308, -86.84069568, -85.09231565, -97.06797015, 
-85.46136187, -84.20157248, -84.68528178, -83.67899935, -77.49694198, 
-88.43532173, -88.06279398, -94.56251908, -86.76971028, -122.0624731, 
-77.61581978, -79.91871388, -71.04567618, -74.13826348, -79.91708618, 
-85.95063428, -82.75350194, -77.41799368, -117.8369637, -115.1551091, 
-96.63990498, -74.53341988, -97.18762718, -111.8724617, -85.65353888, 
-82.10250408, -82.37662408, -95.63365818, -81.71439878, -84.24287668, 
-87.02066117, -94.25486323, -82.81041732, -117.8799774, -94.62745888, 
-84.45473368, -81.15110098, -84.58213288, -118.6379601, -84.6632553, 
-86.71827398, -82.56552868, -97.54349298, -84.88784681, -84.13757728, 
-74.08384478, -97.29644118, -80.00100348, -79.91708618, -81.49222228, 
-122.0370505, -74.06329858, -111.7277681, -96.95180708, -96.80965788, 
-74.26622628, -96.80005245, -79.98056278, -87.79977058, -97.54349298, 
-84.81260358, -86.96550559, -81.61105488, -95.7084137, -97.20547068, 
-84.42066928, -73.16701528, -98.35755551, -95.81624948, -85.46136187, 
-74.09800498, -89.72971898, -97.63605089, -89.40247868, -85.89273868, 
-83.29344078, -96.72618387, -95.03313838, -81.50731626, -111.8443197, 
-87.76237478, -97.51745198, -87.76237478, -90.23712458, -83.61519138, 
-121.9114407, -74.90927108, -80.36580937, -90.13827058, -78.90678928, 
-96.63990498, -84.25439932, -83.25383488, -83.79461948, -86.82142738, 
-86.82142738, -88.12679718, -87.80746759, -76.52698608, -94.47717162, 
-90.70853338, -97.39659408, -81.52005128, -88.18049748, -85.46136187, 
-84.89294298, -76.24251918, -74.51152328, -76.97949628, -84.29902618, 
-99.46534028, -74.00476988, -80.33859089, -80.95456468, -84.45731333, 
-85.65353888, -74.00476988, -90.46154828, -72.64179868, -93.16118228, 
-84.21322458, -93.86649468, -85.01965998, -83.88699788, -84.07321728, 
-95.42330848, -84.58880228, -80.36672868, -81.65153468, -97.00634838, 
-94.35263477, -77.32631998, -94.43496958, -76.67833308, -83.06203458, 
-112.0099692, -84.51459328, -77.04740688, -71.44817608, -98.74972018, 
-77.06914628, -111.700236, -97.1840183, -97.1840183, -87.25788998, 
-84.63809029, -79.83336858, -98.47524008, -96.87205248, -117.8699727, 
-81.43290568, -97.1840183, -83.90284508, -97.41352897, -81.56227998, 
-95.29927518, -95.91241468, -85.22404648, -80.31384208, -87.14492663, 
-81.61324968, -82.55393578, -76.57204258, -95.35528138, -84.44416858, 
-80.98000783, -80.73098658, -88.33244818, -75.18902938, -80.07311268, 
-77.56057068, -81.95715248, -97.14402938, -111.4987143), lat = c(36.10732598, 
32.44879598, 29.50962608, 35.00136258, 38.88771948, 41.77643578, 
33.14457978, 41.00829888, 43.05468238, 42.37087558, 40.58709028, 
38.18249178, 33.31196258, 33.49136798, 38.84533258, 29.70678378, 
35.08626578, 33.83726372, 41.84413698, 35.04801798, 34.08587568, 
29.51558548, 30.11686506, 33.95535038, 34.80871098, 30.01934188, 
34.83475943, 33.20290788, 33.70414798, 33.52194898, 38.31120168, 
33.64745948, 33.64337498, 33.70414798, 40.35971808, 36.10732598, 
41.51429564, 32.33882361, 33.73253228, 26.29575048, 28.67288008, 
39.71866118, 29.19785638, 38.99249108, 32.54625518, 40.59395294, 
34.27071337, 35.64017788, 33.49136798, 39.10795188, 40.96543398, 
40.16204478, 33.50156288, 40.14893285, 35.92199668, 39.28216538, 
40.19106692, 39.87247288, 30.3107932, 38.64147858, 40.40784808, 
36.41111068, 34.83429638, 34.00496348, 29.45791198, 38.21921898, 
34.34833658, 35.00136258, 37.82171518, 42.59513573, 30.28431188, 
34.16732048, 39.67996348, 39.14099748, 26.10837898, 40.29214178, 
38.22237688, 32.95754778, 33.67659488, 41.06186388, 40.03537988, 
40.16124718, 35.09813768, 32.69877078, 40.47704631, 33.22280098, 
32.76097348, 39.17599778, 34.31883459, 38.85670728, 35.49470678, 
28.25222488, 38.98929368, 40.25681955, 39.87652218, 32.20532208, 
31.94421008, 30.27475558, 36.34679978, 40.66129808, 37.58102268, 
28.56341658, 38.22237688, 37.27720908, 41.48299458, 41.05002758, 
33.49761598, 32.58151308, 45.01489188, 33.91165268, 31.55658684, 
26.58865538, 35.36513988, 39.92077358, 33.91411259, 36.06752048, 
40.50735508, 33.10938768, 40.25045128, 33.97458258, 37.01664351, 
31.97604718, 32.50980148, 44.05241418, 39.74214978, 32.96708678, 
32.50980148, 36.17021138, 35.64596118, 40.65932228, 31.78036138, 
35.60102728, 34.82822998, 32.03424198, 33.63372588, 33.22207953, 
28.33920008, 33.74320358, 33.10739598, 37.40542318, 34.93792668, 
33.66580008, 33.13140438, 33.74320358, 37.82362028, 28.25222488, 
28.18868198, 33.31418398, 35.37713318, 34.54116787, 36.11695718, 
30.08778218, 37.22634648, 39.87657218, 37.01664351, 36.72009818, 
34.27071337, 33.72621938, 30.20279438, 43.59153138, 37.95120578, 
32.00968968, 39.35178538, 38.78473398, 35.36513988, 38.99249108, 
39.36024378, 37.40542318, 33.17939948, 39.08705548, 26.65280338, 
38.46740368, 36.74358188, 33.23957504, 29.78038638, 33.10020598, 
29.70678378, 39.40391548, 39.39562828, 29.75716528, 40.97693905, 
33.96708678, 33.82380068, 39.87239567, 37.34609318, 35.04664038, 
34.84618218, 32.88629868, 32.97397338, 29.80646498, 37.01664351, 
28.00520727, 33.03312998, 36.12853148, 41.85345268, 36.88626648, 
28.58796488, 34.17193358, 35.12262078, 43.65372488, 40.41507978, 
37.22634648, 37.58102268, 38.468807, 32.76097348, 39.50013948, 
40.27493053, 34.83962208, 27.89497218, 34.87041428, 43.59153138, 
40.41507978, 33.50419248, 32.94037018, 42.27043728, 32.69582298, 
38.99086398, 32.64768914, 31.60162748, 38.99086398, 32.76611728, 
29.51558548, 41.59573298, 42.37087558, 37.67563818, 32.76611728, 
33.52666998, 42.56615518, 29.69165498, 39.33146034, 40.17906867, 
38.29118748, 28.07220498, 35.39803918, 34.14721798, 42.27274136, 
32.33882361, 36.27357057, 36.02692398, 33.76598017, 36.77162658, 
42.54612898, 39.87247288, 38.75463903, 32.61326288, 28.48847278, 
32.69521158, 33.30887498, 38.00152948, 39.71867492, 32.90725602, 
39.22025778, 34.31883459, 32.30953918, 36.05078908, 38.02338678, 
38.81701848, 35.08511888, 29.65766238, 38.01895668, 39.28216538, 
32.91413308, 38.99249108, 34.26145165, 32.84807298, 33.10938768, 
32.95965598, 36.04333015, 37.06503098, 40.26684448, 40.34071004, 
36.12457728, 39.14099748, 29.56507468, 40.78046553, 28.00051148, 
34.64819028, 38.86657272, 34.33230988, 35.59326368, 33.34404958, 
33.56754367, 36.12669528, 32.60263485, 30.87214588, 33.96708678, 
32.58999489, 37.38865258, 41.54620322, 41.87952908, 39.08705548, 
36.09872898, 37.64368638, 37.47914568, 35.99428318, 42.41426838, 
41.07262058, 37.40542318, 37.82362028, 40.14658785, 37.29092098, 
34.13509508, 35.98911378, 32.95787838, 40.78828328, 33.10739598, 
40.51634608, 38.25340428, 35.06254338, 34.18737408, 29.91826658, 
30.08778218, 39.53254228, 31.0031144, 39.00282513, 40.64603811, 
33.63372588, 39.17599778, 34.02434888, 28.52783688, 39.11255928, 
34.20781808, 33.32570444, 34.83429638, 27.98995798, 35.59093358, 
38.20448855, 33.50598268, 40.64518598, 32.68366548, 37.32855068, 
37.40542318, 31.14762008, 47.60635668, 40.16857808, 40.35971808, 
32.58151308, 32.84730908, 40.85101807, 33.03669303, 40.35560738, 
32.30953918, 35.59093358, 33.36485958, 36.57108509, 35.27217048, 
34.31883459, 33.01843998, 33.91715858, 41.26159558, 31.71609242, 
29.73300988, 32.60263485, 40.95484378, 31.87380178, 27.85922685, 
33.28987498, 39.71866118, 34.55425088, 32.88364675, 29.46812698, 
31.16692932, 33.30887498, 42.08354828, 35.31085698, 42.08354828, 
38.64191088, 32.51393518, 36.55422298, 39.74541188, 26.27896762, 
32.44455428, 34.92203328, 32.95787838, 33.47038112, 42.56761058, 
34.61794568, 36.03372748, 36.03372748, 41.54661958, 41.88712962, 
37.17331268, 37.14883482, 35.82400808, 32.61046218, 30.29705038, 
30.64371348, 32.60263485, 35.15882908, 36.90033788, 39.41699098, 
38.64147858, 33.77088738, 27.43169458, 40.36881888, 25.68622927, 
35.15796298, 40.35881961, 38.25340428, 40.36881888, 38.63991368, 
41.84413698, 44.92486158, 30.57063358, 41.60241088, 33.00437918, 
35.88736838, 34.08545128, 30.01759548, 39.18909628, 27.24509378, 
41.11280098, 32.69582298, 35.45946563, 37.53987458, 39.28459628, 
39.43264958, 42.33899238, 33.67952778, 36.50558638, 39.14099748, 
41.84224558, 35.75233768, 39.04869768, 33.36367508, 33.3440496, 
47.08909721, 36.55810588, 35.40930653, 40.34366338, 29.23686828, 
32.58051268, 33.78569401, 31.44026068, 47.08909721, 33.99073768, 
32.36677043, 41.08626038, 32.29917593, 36.10732598, 34.01956488, 
36.94964441, 32.94696163, 41.47999188, 35.57252518, 39.40572818, 
29.57354898, 33.66281638, 34.20879823, 35.39518728, 41.84771558, 
40.02215508, 40.33475298, 39.13299018, 28.13386108, 32.72208508, 
40.66693868), state = c("Oklahoma", "Mississippi", "Texas", "North Carolina", 
"Missouri", "Connecticut", "California", "New York", "Wisconsin", 
"Massachusetts", "Pennsylvania", "Virginia", "Alabama", "Georgia", 
"Virginia", "Texas", "Tennessee", "Georgia", "Connecticut", "South Carolina", 
"Georgia", "Texas", "Texas", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Texas", "Alabama", 
"Texas", "Alabama", "South Carolina", "Virginia", "Alabama", 
"California", "Alabama", "Utah", "Oklahoma", "Ohio", "Alabama", 
"Georgia", "Florida", "Florida", "Indiana", "Florida", "Virginia", 
"Texas", "Ohio", "California", "Oklahoma", "Georgia", "Maryland", 
"Ohio", "Pennsylvania", "California", "Ohio", "Tennessee", "Maryland", 
"Ohio", "Ohio", "Florida", "Maryland", "Utah", "North Carolina", 
"Alabama", "Georgia", "Texas", "Kentucky", "Georgia", "North Carolina", 
"Kentucky", "Michigan", "Florida", "South Carolina", "Ohio", 
"Maryland", "Florida", "Utah", "Kentucky", "California", "Georgia", 
"Ohio", "Ohio", "Ohio", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Pennsylvania", 
"Alabama", "Texas", "Missouri", "Oklahoma", "Virginia", "Oklahoma", 
"Florida", "Maryland", "Pennsylvania", "Indiana", "Georgia", 
"Georgia", "Texas", "Tennessee", "Pennsylvania", "Virginia", 
"Florida", "Kentucky", "Virginia", "Ohio", "New Jersey", "Alabama", 
"Texas", "Minnesota", "Georgia", "Arizona", "Florida", "North Carolina", 
"New Jersey", "Arkansas", "North Carolina", "Pennsylvania", "Texas", 
"Pennsylvania", "Georgia", "Virginia", "Georgia", "Texas", "Oregon", 
"New Jersey", "California", "Texas", "North Carolina", "Tennessee", 
"Pennsylvania", "Texas", "Arkansas", "Georgia", "Georgia", "California", 
"Alabama", "Florida", "Georgia", "Texas", "Virginia", "Mississippi", 
"Alabama", "Texas", "Georgia", "Kentucky", "Florida", "Florida", 
"Arizona", "North Carolina", "Alabama", "North Carolina", "Florida", 
"Virginia", "Ohio", "Virginia", "Virginia", "California", "California", 
"Florida", "Michigan", "California", "Georgia", "West Virginia", 
"Missouri", "North Carolina", "Virginia", "Maryland", "Virginia", 
"Alabama", "Missouri", "Florida", "Virginia", "Virginia", "Arizona", 
"Texas", "Georgia", "Texas", "Maryland", "Maryland", "Texas", 
"Pennsylvania", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Indiana", "Virginia", 
"South Carolina", "Alabama", "Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "Virginia", 
"Florida", "Texas", "Tennessee", "Illinois", "Virginia", "Florida", 
"South Carolina", "Tennessee", "Idaho", "New Jersey", "Virginia", 
"Virginia", "Missouri", "Texas", "New Jersey", "Pennsylvania", 
"South Carolina", "Florida", "Alabama", "Michigan", "New Jersey", 
"California", "Texas", "Illinois", "Texas", "Maryland", "Texas", 
"Texas", "Maryland", "Texas", "Texas", "Ohio", "Massachusetts", 
"Virginia", "Texas", "Arizona", "Michigan", "Texas", "Ohio", 
"Pennsylvania", "Virginia", "Florida", "California", "Georgia", 
"Michigan", "Alabama", "Oklahoma", "Tennessee", "South Carolina", 
"Virginia", "Massachusetts", "Ohio", "Missouri", "Texas", "Florida", 
"Texas", "Arizona", "Virginia", "New Jersey", "Texas", "Ohio", 
"South Carolina", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "Kentucky", "Virginia", 
"North Carolina", "Texas", "Virginia", "Maryland", "Texas", "Virginia", 
"Georgia", "Texas", "Texas", "California", "Oklahoma", "Virginia", 
"New Jersey", "Indiana", "Tennessee", "Maryland", "Texas", "Pennsylvania", 
"Florida", "California", "Missouri", "Georgia", "Oklahoma", "Alabama", 
"Georgia", "Oklahoma", "Alabama", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia", 
"Virginia", "Illinois", "Illinois", "Missouri", "Tennessee", 
"California", "Virginia", "North Carolina", "Massachusetts", 
"New Jersey", "Virginia", "Kentucky", "Ohio", "Virginia", "California", 
"Nevada", "Texas", "New Jersey", "Texas", "Utah", "Kentucky", 
"South Carolina", "South Carolina", "Texas", "Florida", "Ohio", 
"Alabama", "Missouri", "Ohio", "California", "Missouri", "Georgia", 
"Florida", "Ohio", "California", "Georgia", "Alabama", "Florida", 
"Oklahoma", "Kentucky", "Georgia", "New York", "Texas", "Virginia", 
"Virginia", "Georgia", "Washington", "New Jersey", "Utah", "Texas", 
"Texas", "New Jersey", "Texas", "Pennsylvania", "Alabama", "Oklahoma", 
"Georgia", "Tennessee", "North Carolina", "Oklahoma", "Texas", 
"Georgia", "Connecticut", "Texas", "Texas", "Alabama", "New Jersey", 
"Mississippi", "Texas", "Mississippi", "Indiana", "Georgia", 
"Texas", "Texas", "Georgia", "Arizona", "Illinois", "Oklahoma", 
"Illinois", "Missouri", "Georgia", "California", "New Jersey", 
"Florida", "Mississippi", "North Carolina", "Texas", "Georgia", 
"Michigan", "Georgia", "Tennessee", "Tennessee", "Illinois", 
"Illinois", "Virginia", "Missouri", "Arkansas", "Texas", "Florida", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Tennessee", "Virginia", "New Jersey", 
"Maryland", "Georgia", "Texas", "New Jersey", "Florida", "North Carolina", 
"Ohio", "Kentucky", "New Jersey", "Missouri", "Connecticut", 
"Minnesota", "Florida", "Iowa", "Georgia", "Tennessee", "Georgia", 
"Texas", "Ohio", "Florida", "Ohio", "Texas", "Arkansas", "Virginia", 
"Missouri", "Maryland", "Michigan", "Arizona", "Tennessee", "Maryland", 
"Rhode Island", "Oklahoma", "Maryland", "Arizona", "Texas", "North Dakota", 
"Tennessee", "Tennessee", "Pennsylvania", "Texas", "Texas", "California", 
"Georgia", "North Dakota", "Georgia", "Texas", "Ohio", "Texas", 
"Oklahoma", "Georgia", "Virginia", "Alabama", "Ohio", "North Carolina", 
"Maryland", "Texas", "Georgia", "South Carolina", "North Carolina", 
"Illinois", "Pennsylvania", "Pennsylvania", "Virginia", "Florida", 
"Texas", "Utah"), newcounty = c("tulsa", "madison", "bexar", 
"union", "jackson", "hartford", "san diego", "westchester", "waukesha", 
"middlesex", "allegheny", "spotsylvania", "shelby", "clayton", 
"prince william", "harris", "hamilton", "walton", "hartford", 
"spartanburg", "gwinnett", "bexar", "travis", "gwinnett", "murray", 
"harris", "lauderdale", "collin", "jefferson", "aiken", "spotsylvania", 
"jefferson", "orange", "jefferson", "utah", "tulsa", "cuyahoga", 
"montgomery", "carroll", "collier", "sumter", "hancock", "volusia", 
"loudoun", "gregg", "marion", "los angeles", "oklahoma", "clayton", 
"howard", "wayne", "bucks", "riverside", "miami", "knox", "montgomery", 
"delaware", "montgomery", "duval", "charles", "utah", "person", 
"madison", "barrow", "bexar", "jefferson", "hall", "union", "johnson", 
"oakland", "suwannee", "lexington", "montgomery", "montgomery", 
"broward", "utah", "jefferson", "san diego", "douglas", "summit", 
"franklin", "union", "shelby", "dallas", "allegheny", "shelby", 
"tarrant", "platte", "pushmataha", "fairfax", "sequoyah", "brevard", 
"prince georges", "washington", "marion", "dodge", "crisp", "travis", 
"carter", "beaver", "henrico", "hernando", "jefferson", "chesterfield", 
"cuyahoga", "bergen", "jefferson", "dallas", "ramsey", "oconee", 
"cochise", "lee", "mecklenburg", "burlington", "clark", "forsyth", 
"allegheny", "collin", "washington", "gwinnett", "montgomery", 
"chatham", "ellis", "deschutes", "gloucester", "san diego", "ellis", 
"forsyth", "warren", "allegheny", "el paso", "jackson", "rabun", 
"chatham", "orange", "shelby", "brevard", "douglas", "denton", 
"botetourt", "alcorn", "jefferson", "denton", "douglas", "hardin", 
"brevard", "pasco", "maricopa", "wayne", "franklin", "forsyth", 
"clay", "roanoke", "fairfield", "montgomery", "washington", "los angeles", 
"orange", "duval", "isabella", "marin", "chatham", "berkeley", 
"st louis", "mecklenburg", "loudoun", "baltimore city", "botetourt", 
"shelby", "jackson", "palm beach", "stafford", "virginia beach", 
"maricopa", "harris", "jefferson", "harris", "baltimore", "baltimore", 
"harris", "butler", "cobb", "gwinnett", "henry", "campbell", 
"york", "lauderdale", "tarrant", "hunt", "harris", "montgomery", 
"polk", "denton", "davidson", "du page", "virginia beach", "orange", 
"darlington", "hamilton", "ada", "monmouth", "roanoke", "henrico", 
"cole", "tarrant", "atlantic", "washington", "greenville", "hillsborough", 
"madison", "isabella", "monmouth", "orange", "tarrant", "mchenry", 
"dallas", "montgomery", "dallas", "mclennan", "montgomery", "kaufman", 
"bexar", "cuyahoga", "middlesex", "henrico", "kaufman", "maricopa", 
"oakland", "harris", "butler", "cumberland", "madison", "polk", 
"kern", "forsyth", "calhoun", "montgomery", "tulsa", "knox", 
"lexington", "virginia beach", "franklin", "montgomery", "st charles", 
"tarrant", "hernando", "dallas", "maricopa", "albemarle", "salem", 
"dallas", "hamilton", "newberry", "marengo", "lawrence", "anderson", 
"fairfax", "union", "bexar", "louisa", "montgomery", "tarrant", 
"loudoun", "floyd", "tarrant", "collin", "san diego", "tulsa", 
"nottoway", "mercer", "jay", "davidson", "montgomery", "bexar", 
"centre", "hillsborough", "los angeles", "st charles", "hall", 
"oklahoma", "shelby", "carroll", "payne", "lee", "grady", "cobb", 
"houston", "chesterfield", "kendall", "du page", "jackson", "davidson", 
"alameda", "chesterfield", "guilford", "middlesex", "bergen", 
"botetourt", "hardin", "delaware", "chesterfield", "los angeles", 
"clark", "dallas", "morris", "denton", "salt lake", "jefferson", 
"spartanburg", "abbeville", "harris", "clay", "warren", "santa rosa", 
"jackson", "morrow", "orange", "platte", "cobb", "orange", "hamilton", 
"los angeles", "coweta", "madison", "hillsborough", "oklahoma", 
"franklin", "henry", "richmond", "tarrant", "roanoke", "botetourt", 
"glynn", "king", "monmouth", "utah", "dallas", "dallas", "essex", 
"collin", "allegheny", "marengo", "oklahoma", "coweta", "robertson", 
"cleveland", "pushmataha", "denton", "fulton", "fairfield", "hamilton", 
"fort bend", "lee", "bergen", "simpson", "nueces", "choctaw", 
"hancock", "stephens", "dallas", "galveston", "glynn", "maricopa", 
"cook", "cleveland", "cook", "st louis city", "houston", "monterey", 
"camden", "broward", "madison", "cumberland", "dallas", "henry", 
"oakland", "white", "williamson", "williamson", "will", "cook", 
"newport news", "jasper", "craighead", "tarrant", "duval", "mobile", 
"lee", "bradley", "norfolk", "atlantic", "charles", "de kalb", 
"webb", "monmouth", "miami-dade", "mecklenburg", "auglaize", 
"jefferson", "monmouth", "st louis", "hartford", "ramsey", "leon", 
"dallas", "troup", "knox", "gwinnett", "harris", "hamilton", 
"st lucie", "summit", "dallas", "crawford", "henrico", "clay", 
"baltimore", "wayne", "maricopa", "scott", "montgomery", "providence", 
"custer", "montgomery", "maricopa", "denton", "cass", "montgomery", 
"mcminn", "allegheny", "bexar", "dallas", "orange", "mcintosh", 
"cass", "gwinnett", "johnson", "summit", "smith", "tulsa", "polk", 
"floyd", "bibb", "cuyahoga", "buncombe", "baltimore", "brazoria", 
"fulton", "richland", "cabarrus", "kane", "philadelphia", "allegheny", 
"loudoun", "polk", "tarrant", "summit")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "23", "24", "25", "27", 
"28", "29", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "39", "40", 
"41", "42", "43", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "52", "53", 
"54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", 
"65", "66", "67", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", 
"77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "88", 
"89", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", 
"138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", 
"151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", "159", "160", 
"161", "162", "163", "164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", 
"170", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", 
"179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", 
"188", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", 
"197", "198", "199", "200", "201", "202", "203", "205", "206", 
"207", "208", "209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", 
"216", "217", "218", "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", 
"225", "226", "227", "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", 
"234", "236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", 
"244", "245", "246", "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", 
"253", "254", "255", "256", "257", "258", "259", "261", "262", 
"263", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", "272", 
"274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", "281", "282", 
"283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", "290", "291", 
"292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", "299", "300", 
"301", "302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "308", "309", "310", 
"311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "317", "318", "319", "321", 
"322", "323", "324", "325", "326", "327", "328", "329", "331", 
"333", "334", "335", "336", "337", "338", "339", "340", "341", 
"342", "343", "344", "345", "346", "348", "349", "350", "351", 
"353", "354", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360", "361", "362", 
"363", "364", "365", "366", "367", "368", "369", "370", "371", 
"372", "373", "374", "375", "376", "377", "378", "379", "380", 
"381", "382", "383", "384", "385", "386", "387", "388", "389", 
"390", "391", "392", "393", "394", "395", "396", "397", "398", 
"399", "400", "401", "402", "403", "404", "405", "406", "407", 
"408", "409", "410", "411", "412", "413", "414", "415", "416", 
"417", "418", "419", "420", "421", "422", "423", "424", "425", 
"426", "427", "428", "429", "430", "431", "432", "433", "434", 
"435", "436", "437", "438", "439", "440", "441", "442", "444", 
"445", "446", "447", "448", "449", "450", "451", "452", "453", 
"454", "455", "456", "457", "458", "459", "460", "461", "462", 
"463", "464", "465", "466", "467", "469", "471", "472", "473", 
"474", "475", "476", "477", "478", "479", "480", "482", "483", 
"484", "485", "486", "487", "488", "489", "490"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `summarise` + `unnest`. Use `mutate` so other columns are maintained.

```
library(usmap)
library(dplyr)

pointsDF %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  mutate(new = fips(state = first(state), county = newcounty))

#   lon   lat state          newcounty   new  
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          <chr>     <chr>
#1 -95.9  36.1 Oklahoma       tulsa     40143
#2 -90.1  32.4 Mississippi    madison   28089
#3 -98.3  29.5 Texas          bexar     48029
#4 -80.7  35.0 North Carolina union     37179
```

---

Or keeping the approach similar to your original attempt do :

```
pointsDF %>%  
  group_by(state) %>%  
  summarise(new = list(fips(state = first(state), county = newcounty)), 
            lon = first(lon), lat  = first(lat)) %>%  
  unnest(c(new))

#   state   new     lon   lat
#   <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Alabama 01117 -86.8  33.3
# 2 Alabama 01077 -86.8  33.3
# 3 Alabama 01073 -86.8  33.3
# 4 Alabama 01073 -86.8  33.3
# 5 Alabama 01073 -86.8  33.3
# 6 Alabama 01101 -86.8  33.3
# 7 Alabama 01089 -86.8  33.3
# 8 Alabama 01117 -86.8  33.3
# 9 Alabama 01073 -86.8  33.3
#10 Alabama 01117 -86.8  33.3
# … with 431 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get this error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `new`.
x Input `new` can't be recycled to size 26.
ℹ Input `new` is `fips(state = first(state), county = newcounty)`.
ℹ Input `new` must be size 26 or 1, not 25.
ℹ The error occured in group 1: state = "Alabama".

Comment: Are you using on the same data as in your post? Do you have the same error for that data?

Comment: Yes, but the data I posted was just the first four rows. My data set is around 450 rows long so I didn't post it all. Should I edit the post to include the entire data set?

Comment: Yes or atleast check after how many rows do you get that error? The error suggests that there is some issue with `state = "Alabama"`. Check only those rows. Do you have some unusual data that is causing error in that group? do you have `NA` values?

Comment: I looked and don't have any ```NA``` values there. The data looks fine, and what concerns me further is that ```Alabama``` is the first group alphabetically

Comment: It says there are counties which do not have valid name. For example - `du page` in `Illinois`.

Comment: I don't understand why it's not working since the initial code from the post is working. When I run this code ```pointsDF <- pointsDF %>% 
group_by(state) %>% 
summarise(new = list(fips(state = first(state), county = newcounty))) %>% 
unnest(c(new))``` it works but it just deletes the other columns. I'm lost why the original fips command works but your code which should work does not. R boggles my mind sometimes

Comment: Hi Ronak, unfortunately I went back and checked the results from the above code, and found that the updated code you posted is giving me some screwy results. When I use it, it repeats the county for the first observation in every state. So, every result for a given state will have the same county, even though the county should be different for many of the observations. I will update the post to reflect this

Comment: What do you mean? I see that `new` column has all different values in each row.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
pointsDF %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
   mutate(new = fips(state = state[1], county = newcounty))
```